# Fixed div top of web page broken result

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed header with a full screen background image under that my sections. what i am trying to do is if i have a alert it will echo above the whole page pushing down the header and hero. but it either wont show up or when i do get it to show it wont stay fixed and scrolls with the page.

```
.sitrep {
    top 0;  
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000; 
}



.siteHeader {
    min-height: 76px;
    height: 76px;
    overflow: visible;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #f4f4f4;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
}





#hero {
    height: 100vh;
}

.hero {
    background: url(images/hero-bg.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    background-color: #000;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

#hero-content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0%;
}

#hero-content a {
    background-color: #131313;
    padding-top: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#hero-content img {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 2px;
    max-height: 145px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-bottom: 53px;
    padding: 5px;
}


<div class="sitrep">
<div class="alert-status">  
 <div class="info">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
  <strong>Announcement!</strong> anouncment goes here.
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="siteHeader">my header</div>

<!-- Hero Unit -->
<div id="hero" class="hero">
    <div id="hero-content">
        <img src="content/images/logo-dt.png" class="img-responsive">
        <a class="button" role="button" href="#base">Learn more</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using `.sitrep` in your css, which is looking for sitrep as class. But you are using sitrep as id. So try using `#sitrep` in your css. Should propably fix your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up `class`es and `ID`'s.

In your HTML, you give the element the ID of `sitrep`, whereas you are giving the styles to the elements with the *class* of `siterep`.

Try either of the following options and you'll be set :

**Changing the element attribute:** `<div id="sitrep">` to `<div class="sitrep">`

**Changing the CSS to fit the proper elements:** `.sitrep {` to `#sitrep {`

Happy coding !

Comment: @DataDev You have multiple `sitrep` in your HTML, in your edit you have only replaced one of them with a class. Perhaps changing the other will solve your problem.

Comment: @DBS I have updated the code and double checked its still the same result the alert does not push down the header or the hero it simply float overtop of the header